# How to send a whole object to Angular 2 from JSP?

Tags: json, jsp, angular

Currently my application is a mix of JSP and Angular 2.  To invoke the Angular 2 application from JSP I use url

```
app/index.html/#/calendar/${rent.id}
```

In my Angular 2 application I create a routing path that is linked to the CalendarComponent

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '',   redirectTo: '/calendar/1', pathMatch: 'full'},
    { path: 'calendar/:id', component: CalendarComponent}
];
```

Then in NgModule I initialize this routing path

```
@NgModule({
…
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ useHash: true })
 ],
…
})
```

The deficiency with this approach is that on the Angular  side I need to retrieve the object again based on the id. That results in one more call to the server.  How to avoid this call getting the object from JSP?  I am thinking about a JSON call but not sure how to realize it

Comment: You could use JSP to write a <script> tag in your `index.html`, e.g. `<script>window.myData = { title: "foo"};</script>` and then access the `myData` global variable from your Angular app, but it's far from ideal.

Comment: I am thinking about a JSON call

Comment: That'd be a lot cleaner, but you said you wanted to avoid the additional server request.

Comment: Yes, because I can construct a JSON object by JavaScript